# Unknown SQL Queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have just "completed" my first Entity Framework application and used Express Profiler 2.2 to see what is going on with the database.

When my program start I get some SQL queries that I don't understand.
Is this something I should worry about?

NB! I have **not** enabled Migrations!

```
exec sp_reset_connection

SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME IN ('dbo.AssemblyCode','dbo.Fixture','dbo.HistoryData','dbo.LaserData','dbo.QuarterCode','dbo.SerialNumber','dbo.WeekCode')
    OR t.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetadata'

exec sp_reset_connection

exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'DCMarkerEF.DCLasermarkContext'

exec sp_reset_connection

SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]

exec sp_reset_connection

SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[ModelHash] AS [ModelHash]
    FROM [dbo].[EdmMetadata] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[Id] DESC
```

Comment: Noting to worry abot, but you can get rid of some of them, see this: https://romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter/

Comment: OK, since this is "built" in EF I think I leave it as is. It doesn't take much time (on my small test database anyway) Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to worry about, but you can get rid of some of them, see this: romiller.com/2014/06/10/reducing-code-first-database-chatter

Answer (score 0):

Please, try it:

https://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/removing-edmmetadata-table-in-ef-code-first

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
```